# Is there a label for \part to use with \autoref?

Tags: cross-referencing

If I write:

```
\chapter{}\label{chap:name1}
```

I can write:

```
See it in the \autoref{chap:name1}.
```

But what about the parts?

```
\part{}\label{?:name2}
```

So I could write:

```
See it in the \autoref{?:name2}.
```

Note: I have found more labels here (but not a label for the parts): http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing#Fixing_wrong_labels

Comment: Parts too can have labels. `\part{}\label{part:name2}` should work.

Comment: (almost?!) everything that has an automatic numbering can be labeled.

Comment: Yes! Both `\autoref{part:name2}` and `\nameref{part:name2}` work perfectly. Feel free to answer the question. Thanks you both! :)

Comment: How you name your labels is completely up to you. Something like `\part{Foo}\label{foo}` and then `\autoref{foo}` works just nicely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement to use any specific labelling *schema* that accompanies a `\label`. However, it does in code legibility, of course.

So, for example, it is not necessary to use `\label{part:<labelname>}` when you label a `\part`, or `\label{sec:<labelname>}` for labelling a `\section` or

```
\label{<type>:<labelname>}
```

in general. This is purely user or style choice. You can use

```
\label{<whatever you like>}
```

Some packages require this schema-approach to labelling in order to provide similar functionality to what `\autoref` of [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) provides: [`fancyref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyref) and [`prettyref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/prettyref)